# Displaying different Tkinter labels each time a button is hit

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, label

is there anyway in tkinter | python  3.4 i can have a button and a label and each time i hit that button the label changes its text? text. i have a maths equations program im making and want to print the answer as a text in screen instead of to the python console print.

```
label = tk.Label(self, text = "").pack()
button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Button").pack(fill=X)
```

i want that button to change that label somehow.

if not a label is there a different method?

Comment: Note that `label` and `button1` in your code snippet above both point to `None`, the value returned by the `pack()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Bind a callback function as the button's command. In that callback function, reconfigure the label's text.

```
label = tk.Label(self, text="")
label.pack()
e1 = tk.Entry(self)
e1.pack()
e2 = tk.Entry(self)
e2.pack()
button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Button", command=my_func)
button1.pack(fill=X)

def my_func():
    label.config(text=str(float(e1.get())*float(e2.get())))
```

The example above changes the `label` to the product of whatever is in `e1` and `e2`.